# Adding legend to matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, pixel

I am following the Randy Olson approach to make beautiful time trends graphs (see [here](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/28/how-to-make-beautiful-data-visualizations-in-python-with-matplotlib/)).

When I plot the following code:

```
tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232)]  
for i in range(len(tableau20)):    
    r, g, b = tableau20[i]    
    tableau20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)   

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 14))    

# Remove the plot frame lines. They are unnecessary chartjunk.    
ax = plt.subplot(111)    
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)    

# Ensure that the axis ticks only show up on the bottom and left of the plot.    
# Ticks on the right and top of the plot are generally unnecessary chartjunk.    
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()    
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()    

majors = ['Number of findings (total)', 'Business Ethics Findings']

for rank, column in enumerate(majors):    
    plt.plot(monthly_df.argrc__End_Date__c.values, monthly_df[column.replace("\n", " ")].values,    
            lw=2.5, color=tableau20[rank])    
    y_pos = monthly_df[column.replace("\n", " ")].values[-1] - 0.5 
    if column == "Number of findings (total)":    
        y_pos += 0.5    
    elif column == 'Business Ethics Findings':    
        y_pos -= 0.5    
    plt.text(2018.1, y_pos, column, fontsize=12, color=tableau20[rank])
```

I get this error:

[image]

If I eliminate

```
 plt.text(2016, y_pos, column, fontsize=12, color=tableau20[rank])
```

Instead I get the two lines plotted on the graph correctly, but with no legend. How do I show the names of my columns?

EDIT

I am adding here the traceback for further information. I hope this is helpful.

```
C:\Users\filippo.sebastio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py:107: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    239 
    240     if 'png' in formats:
--> 241         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    242     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    243         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    123 
    124     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 125     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    126     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    127     if fmt == 'svg':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2261                 orientation=orientation,
   2262                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2263                 **kwargs)
   2264         finally:
   2265             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    515 
    516     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 517         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    518         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    519         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    427         Draw the figure using the renderer
    428         """
--> 429         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    430         # acquire a lock on the shared font cache
    431         RendererAgg.lock.acquire()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in get_renderer(self, cleared)
    452 
    453         if need_new_renderer:
--> 454             self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
    455             self._lastKey = key
    456         elif cleared:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in __init__(self, width, height, dpi)
     99         self.width = width
    100         self.height = height
--> 101         self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi)
    102         self._filter_renderers = []
    103 

ValueError: Image size of 312943x821 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

<Figure size 864x1008 with 1 Axes>
```

Comment: Please copy the traceback instead of pasting an image

Comment: That amount of pixels is enormous. What is the dpi of the figure (i.e. what's the output of `fig.dpi`)?

Comment: the dpi of the figure is 72

Comment: Note that we can't figure out what's wrong without a [mcve], i.e. a code that defines all variables and is runnable by itself. Here, the problem seems to be that the text is way outside the figure, which of course has to do with the coordinates you use.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  can you help me figure out what y_pos = monthly_df[column.replace("\n", " ")].values[-1] - 0.5  does?

Comment: It takes a string `column`, replaces every occurance of the string `"\n"` by a white space. The resulting string is used to identify a column in the dataframe. Then it takes the last value of that column and substract 0.5 from it.